# http instead of https for heroku hosted app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, heroku, https

I have a ruby on rails 4 app on Heroku (`my_app.herokuapp.com`). I registered a domain `my_domain.com` and created a CNAME (alias) to point to `my_app.herokuapp.com`. So now when I type `www.my_domain.com` it serves the app on `my_app.herokuapp.com`. But it tries to serve it using https and not http and before displaying anything complains "The connection is untrusted". How can temporarily fix this by changing it to http? I mean when I type `www.my_domain.com` in the browser I want it to serve `http://my_app.herokuapp.com` and not `https://my_app.herokuapp.com`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out `config.force_ssl = true` in config/environments/production.rb